# Type.GetMethod() returns null even though method definitely exists

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

Given the following code why is method variable null?

```
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(SomeClass) };
var listRef = typeof(List<>);
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listRef.MakeGenericType(typeArgs));
var method = list.GetType().GetMethod("Add‌​", BindingFlags.Default, null, typeArgs, null);
```

I have tried many different overloads and BindingFlags but still never get the MethodInfo for `List<SomeClass>.Add(SomeClass item)`.

Surely it is something simple I am missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `BindingFlags.Default` -> `BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public`, `"Add‌​"` -> `"Add"`.

Comment: I have also tried `BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public` and I dont understand what you mean by `"Add‌​" -> "Add"`

Comment: Try `"Add‌​".Length`. Be sure that you copy-paste your `"Add‌​"`, but not type new one.

Comment: Wow, there was some hidden character in my "Add" string as you suggested.  Make an answer and ill mark it.  Good catch!

Comment: The closure is debatable.  Yes, it's a typographical issue, but not the kind the closure reason was for.  The tough bit about this question is how to make it discoverable for other people who have the same problem, because chances are that the issue has little to do with the method call.  Have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two invisible characters `0x00 0x00` in the string "Add", which is one reason why it does not work. It seems like you did some copy/paste operation.

Next, change the binding flags to `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GenericReflection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(SomeClass) };
            var listRef = typeof(List<>);
            var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listRef.MakeGenericType(typeArgs));
            var method = list.GetType().GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, typeArgs, null);
            Console.WriteLine(method);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch!  How did you notice the invisible characters?  I am really surprised because I typed the "Add" string and had the correct BindingFlags initially.  When that was not working, I did copy and paste some things trying to get it to work.

Comment: @ShaneRay: Odds are good this is not Thomas Weller's first rodeo. :-)  When you have seen this a few times you get reflexive about checking to see whether there are zero-width spaces, byte order marks, embedded zero characters, that a letter "A" is U+0410 (Cyrillic) instead of U+0041 (Latin), and so on.

Comment: Well, I copy/pasted your code first. When it was not working, I wrote some code which gave me all methods. Clearly, there was a method with the signature as written by you. That made me look at the code in a hex editor.

Comment: I see this has been marked as off topic but I wanted to thank you and @EricLippert for your support.  I have created an open source visual studio extension so I (and hopefully others) do not run into this issue again.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaneRay.InvisibleCharacterVisualizer